# How to setup multiple build environments in Azure DevOps/TFS2018?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

So I have an application that contains an ASP.NET Core backend and a React frontend (pure static).

In our TFS 2018, we have created a Build that does the following:

- Get sources from the repo
- Get Nuget packages (backend)
- Build the backend
- Run backend tests
- Get NPM packages (frontend)
- Build the frontend
- Run frontend tests
- Generate and publish artifacts

Then, a Release pickups those artifacts and deploy them to an Azure AppService (backend) and an Azure Storage v2 account (frontend).

We currently have only one environment, but we need to support multiple ones. The problem is that the frontend build depends on some environment variables which are not present during the build stage. The build doesn't know where is it going to be deployed yet.

So there are a few options here:

- Generate the frontend build in a Release. This needs a way for the Release to get access to the sources, either via Git or by getting it from an artifact. Latest is really slow because of all the node_modules.
- Build should produce builds artifacts for all posible environments and each Release environment will pick up the proper one.

What's the recommended approach to handle this on TFS 2018?

Comment: Neither of those sound like good options.  You can't publish artifacts in a release pipeline.  Is it just configuration that is different per environment?  Or is the code different depending on environment?  You probably need expand on the dependency in the build process to the environment variables.

Comment: I never said publish artifact in a release pipeline. I said to publish one artifact per enviroment in the build pipeline and pick the proper one in the release.
The frontend is built with webpack and making use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack, so the actual build files are different depending on the environment variables that are present at build time. 
What do you mean by "expand on the dependency in the build process to the environment variables"?